# Why would loading a Zend_Application with a Zend_Config object produce different results from sending the file name?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-application, zend-config

I seem to be having an issue where loading my Zend_Application object with a Zend_Config object produces different results than loading the Zend_Application object with a filename instead. To illustrate my point, I have the two following methods of loading, the first of which works (Mind you all the constants are defined at this point as well:

```
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

This one doesn't work and gives me the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'No default controller directory registered with front controller' in /var/www/RoommateExpenseBuddy/allan/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php:91

Stack trace: #0 /var/www/RoommateExpenseBuddy/allan/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()

#1 /var/www/RoommateExpenseBuddy/allan/public/index.php(36): Zend_Application->run()

#2 {main} thrown in /var/www/RoommateExpenseBuddy/allan/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php on line 91

```
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'Zend/Config.php';
require_once 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';
require_once 'Zend/Debug.php';
$appConfig = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    $appConfig 
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

They both are using the same file which looks like this:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
emailNotice.email = "info@associateinnovations.com"
emailNotice.name = "Roommate Expense Buddy"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.defaultmodule = "global"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = true
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.isdefaulttableadapter = true
resources.db.params.dbname = "db_name"
resources.db.params.username = "db_user"
resources.db.params.password = "mypassword"
resources.db.params.hostname = "localhost"
resources.db.params.charset = "UTF8"
invitation.defaultViewPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/global/views/scripts/invitation"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

My Directory structure looks something like this with the important folders expanded.

```
|~application/
| |~configs/                  
| | |-application.ini                          
| | `-navigation.xml
| |+helpers/
| |+layouts/ 
| |+migrations/
| |~modules/
| | `~global/
| |   |+controllers/ 
| |   |+forms/  
| |   |+models/                                                                    
| |   `+views/                                                                    
| `-Bootstrap.php                                                                 
|+bin/                                                                              
|+data/                                                                            
|+docs/                                                                             
|+library/                                                                       
|+public/                                                                        
`+tests/
```

So to reiterate, Loading an INI file using the filename in the constructor of Zend_Application produces expected results (working app). Passing a Config object inot the constructor of Zend_Application gives me the above error.

Any clue as to why this would make a difference?

Comment: Can you try, for a moment, to delete this lines and see what happens? 
resources.frontController.defaultmodule = "global"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = true

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa I would have to restructure my application a little bit to have that work. One of the things I would have to do is take everything out of global and move it to the directory /application directory. Additionally I would have to remove the Global_ from the beginning of every Controller class. 

To get around the "flaw" I feel I found, I actually added the controller path in my bootstrap

`$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
 $frontController->setControllerDirectory(array(
  'global' => 'modules/global/controllers'
 ));`

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a mismatch with casing. The original default directory was declared without camel casing, while a front controller directory I needed to add was indeed cased.

So this is what I had:

```
resources.frontcontroller.controllerDirectory.default   = APPLICATION_PATH "/default/controllers"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory.mydir     = APPLICATION_PATH "/default/controllers"
```

To summarize, ZF isn't taking into account casing when doing the initial lookup for the application resource. Subsequent lookups of the already instantiated resource have to match the case of the first declaration, however.

**Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract::_resolvePluginResourceName**

```
/**
 * Resolve a plugin resource name
 *
 * Uses, in order of preference
 * - $_explicitType property of resource
 * - Short name of resource (if a matching prefix path is found)
 * - class name (if none of the above are true)
 *
 * The name is then cast to lowercase.
 *
 * @param  Zend_Application_Resource_Resource $resource
 * @return string
 */
protected function _resolvePluginResourceName($resource)
{
    if (isset($resource->_explicitType)) {
        $pluginName = $resource->_explicitType;
    } else  {
        $className  = get_class($resource);
        $pluginName = $className;
        $loader     = $this->getPluginLoader();
        foreach ($loader->getPaths() as $prefix => $paths) {
            if (0 === strpos($className, $prefix)) {
                $pluginName = substr($className, strlen($prefix));
                $pluginName = trim($pluginName, '_');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $pluginName = strtolower($pluginName);
    return $pluginName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'No default controller directory registered with front controller' in /var/www/RoommateExpenseBuddy/allan/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php:91
>
> Stack trace: #0 /var/www/RoommateExpenseBuddy/allan/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
>
> /var/www/RoommateExpenseBuddy/allan/public/index.php(36): Zend_Application->run()
>
> {main} thrown in /var/www/RoommateExpenseBuddy/allan/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php on line 91

Your error message says that no default controller is registered to front controller object. This is happening cause you are trying to use Zend_Config and it may be not loading the array in the right way.

Could you print the $appConfig var with Zend_Debug and post the result to we better help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this I had the same problem:

This was my solution

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory.default = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"

instead of

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"

Comment: I'll give this one a try. Sounds plausible. I'll report back with my findings!